# iOS 11 Drop URL Returning Nil

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have the following code I'm trying to use for dragging a URL from Safari into a collection view and just having it print the URL.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
    for item: UIDragItem in coordinator.session.items {
        item.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeURL as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) in
            if let myURL = url as? URL {
                print (myURL)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Problem is the `print (myURL)` line never gets called and `myURL` is nil.

I'm not sure why this isn't working as `session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypeURL as String])` is `true`, so it seems like that code should work.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT 1**

Adding `print (url);` prints the following.

```
2017-08-08 14:05:38.917080-0600 _____[1351:289923] [Common] _BSMachError: port 9c0b; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
Optional(<62706c69 73743030 a3010203 5f101a68 74747073 3a2f2f77 77772e6d 61637275 6d6f7273 2e636f6d 2f50d104 05557469 746c655f 10384d61 63205275 6d6f7273 3a204170 706c6520 4d616320 694f5320 52756d6f 72732061 6e64204e 65777320 596f7520 43617265 2041626f 7574080c 292a2d33 00000000 00000101 00000000 00000006 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000006e>)
```

It also says `url` is type `NSSecureCoding?`. I used similar code for a share extension and that worked fine.

Comment: What happens if you print `url` directly? What type is it? If it is not convertible to `URL` the conditional cast will fail.

Comment: @Losiowaty Just edited the question to include answers to your questions.

Comment: `NSSecureCoding` is a protocol, so its actuall class is something else, and from the looks of it, it may be `Data`. What happens if you try something like this : `print(String(data: url!, encoding: .utf8))`?

Comment: ```(lldb) p String(data: url!, encoding: .utf8)
(String?) $R0 = nil
  Fix-it applied, fixed expression was: 
    String(data: url! as! Data, encoding: .utf8)```
@Losiowaty

Comment: Ok, last idea - does `type(of: url!)` say something more beside `NSSecureCodeing`?

Comment: Looks like what you're getting is not a URL. If you dump out the contents of what you got it's: `bplist00£_https://www.macrumors.com/PÑUtitle_8Mac Rumors: Apple Mac iOS Rumors and News You Care About)*-3n` ... so looks like a property list.

Comment: @Losiowaty Nope `(NSSecureCoding.Type) $R1 = 0x00000001029ec068`

Comment: @idz Strange... I'm just dragging from the URL bar of Safari to the application. Why would `session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypeURL as String])` be `true` then?

Comment: @idz And just out of curiosity how were you able to get that output?

Comment: @CharlieFish To convert the hex to ASCII I just used an online converter, not sure which one, perhaps http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm

Comment: @CharlieFish As to the deeper question as to why you're getting a property list instead of a URL, I have no idea. If I did I would have written an answer, just hoped my comment might be useful to help with what's going on. Sorry I can't be more help. Will try to take a look at drag n drop soon.