# Drop files in swift app

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, ios11

I want to use `UIDropInteractionDelegate` for dropping resume files from files app to my app. I think I have search the whole google i didn't find any tutorial for this. Everywhere dropping files are just images and strings. How can I use it for files? 
Files could be .txt, .doc, .pdf, .rtf etc.

[Duplicate question pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494871/ios-11-dropinteraction-performdrop-for-files) gives the description how get pdf file. But i want any of the files to accept; and than this code does not give the dropped file location. How would I get the location of file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 11 dropInteraction performDrop for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494871/ios-11-dropinteraction-performdrop-for-files)

Comment: yes, this gives the description how get pdf file. But i want any file to accept. and than this code does not give the dropped file location. How would I get the location of file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like the below?  (I've never done iOS drag/drop before, but taking a guess based on some web searching and cobbling together).

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool 
{
    let identifiers = [kUTTypeURL as String]
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: identifiers) && session.items.count == 1
}
```

For receiving the actual URL, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576496/ios-11-drop-url-returning-nil) is all I could find so far, which looks like a good start though the author has a problem with it.

Comment: this is returning "public.url". How would i use it? sorry for so many questions :/ I'm new to it.